# apostrophe in preg_match_all() is giving me problems

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all, apostrophe

So I've got this piece of code that wont play nice.

```
preg_match_all("/(\{\[)([\w-\d\s\.\|']*)(\]\})/i",$replace_text, $match);
```

What it is *supposed* to do, is allow an apostrophe to be in my replacement text. So in my text, where i have "{[SPIN--they are|they’re]}" it should return "they are" or "they're".
But instead, it simply does nothing and spits out the entire spintax code just as I typed above.

The only time this does not work, is when a replacement text has an apostrophe. It works perfectly everywhere else. Been trying to fix this for two days and I'm about to throw my keyboard through my monitor.

There are many things that my project does and it is imperative to have the {[SPIN-- before specifying the replacement text, and the ]} closing brackets.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: preg_match_all("/(\{\[)([\w-\d\s\.\|\']*)(\]\})/i",$replace_text, $match); use this may be it helps

Comment: "Been trying to fix this for two days" --- please tell it's a joke

Comment: Thanks but that completey broke my script, it just spit out {[text]} which is where all of this stuff goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example string it's not a single quote character, but something that looks similarly

`’` (the actual character) vs `'` (that's what you think it is)

Comment: I tried it both ways:
preg_match_all("/(\{\[)([\w-\d\s\.\|`]*)(\]\})/i",$replace_text, $match);

and 
preg_match_all("/(\{\[)([\w-\d\s\.\|']*)(\]\})/i",$replace_text, $match);

It gives me the same result both ways.

Comment: @Will Smith: what does it mean? I took your code, took your string and replaced that weird quote with normal `'` and it worked.

Comment: @Will Smith: are you kidding now? `’` and ` and `'` are 3 different characters. Use copy-paste instead of guessing characters, or please use **ZOOM** to see the difference between them